# Django template add a counter infront of paragraph

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to loop a string which is save using tinymce textfield, with a counter in front.

Example question description saved in html:

```
<p>What is<strong> if</strong> satement?</p>
```

Template to loop the quesiton:

```
<li>{{forloop.counter}} {{ question.description|safe }}</li>
```

The result:

1

What is **if** satement?

What I tried to achieve:

1 What is **if** satement?

Comment: can you post the generated html?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to be sure what the problem is here, but if I read your question correctly it's just that you have the `<p></p>` tags around the question in your db.  So your template is generating:

```
<li>1 <p>What is<strong> if</strong> satement?</p></li>
```

-- the `<p/>` is a block-level tag, which is why you're getting the "line-break".  Is that what you mean?

**edit:**

I'm not sure why you can't just remove it in your view, before passing it to the template (`question['description'] = question['description'][3:-4]`), but if you really can't, can you add an appropriate CSS selector with `.. .. p {display: inline;}` ??  It's a bit of a hack, but if your hands are so tied...

Comment: @kelvin -- accept the answer, then?  (maybe even upvote it too?)

Comment: Sorry, you did not answer it. I want to have the number in front of the paragraph not next line.

Comment: @kelvin -- well you should take the `<p></p>`s out, somehow, obviously!  How you do that depends on how they get there in the first place.  Another choice, if you really can't remove them, would be to make them `display:inline`, but really that's a poor choice.

Comment: I just cannot take it out, because that is how it is presented to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `<ol>` instead of `<ul>`, then each `<li>` will include the number already?